# PHP POST yields empty result using sqlite3 database

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have a simple web form in HTML using POST and PHP against an SQLite3 database. The form asks for a database id. When entered and hitting submit, the result does not output to the screen.

Here is the code. Please help! It appears the variable is empty. Where am I going wrong?

Original Form HTML (edit_entry1.html):

```
<body bgcolor = "#C7CFCA">
</p></p>
<center><h2>Update a Record<br>
<form method="POST" action="update_record.php">
<br />
<center>
<h3>To update a record click on 'View Database' and find the record ID you want to update and enter that ID here.</h3>
</center>
<table>
  <tr><td><h2>Record ID: </td><td><h2><input style="font-size:20px" type="text" name="archivo" size="80"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" style="font-size:20px"></td><td><input type=reset value="Reset Form" style="font-size:20px"></td>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

This is the corresponding php script (update_record.php):

```
 <?php
{
//open the database
$db = new SQLite3('wc.db');

// Set Variables from POST
$record = $_POST["archivo"];

//now output the data to a simple html table...
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
echo "<html lang=\"en\">\n";
echo "<body bgcolor = \"#C7CFCA\" text = \"black\">\n";
echo "<center>";
echo "<p>Record ID is <?php echo $record ?>.</p>";
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<h2>Update a Record</h2>";
echo "<tr><th><u><h3>ID</th><th><u><h3>Last Name</th><th><u><h3>First Name</th>";
echo "<th><u><h3>Middle Name</th><th><u><h3>Section</th>";
echo "<th><u><h3>Lot</th><th><u><h3>Plot</th><th><u><h3>Burial Date</th><th><u><h3>Veteran</th></tr>\n";

$results = $db->query('SELECT id,last_name,first_name,middle_initial,section,lot,plot,burial_date,veteran FROM burials WHERE id = $record');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    echo "<tr><td><center><h3>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" .
    $row['first_name'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" . $row['middle_initial'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" .
    $row['section'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" . $row['lot'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" . $row['plot'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" . $row['burial_date'] . "</td><td><center><h3>" . $row['veteran'] . "</td></tr>\n";

}

echo "</table>\n";
echo "<p>Record ID is <?php echo $record ?>.</p>";
echo "<label for=\"sql\"><h3>What do you want to update? </label>";

echo "<select id=\"option\">";
  echo "<h3><option value=\"last_name\"><h3>Last Name</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"fist_name\"><h3>First Name</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"middle_initial\"><h3>Middle Name</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"section\"><h3>Section</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"lot\"><h3>Lot</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"plot\"><h3>Plot</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"burial_date\"><h3>Burial Date</option>";
  echo "<option value=\"veteran\"><h3>Veteran Status</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<h2><input style=\"font-size:15px\" type=\"text\" name=\"opt\" size=\"30\">";
echo "</body>\n";
echo "</html>";

}
?>
```

When I put, say, 1 as the record id in the form, nothing is outputted. I'm new to this and would definitely appreciate some pointers/tips.

Comment: First of all try putting  $record as id = '$record' in your SELECT statement...

Comment: I tried single and double quotes to no avail. I also tried ...id = \'$record\' and id = \"$record\". Nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should consider using the prepare/bind/execute pattern. Use example 1 in the [SQLITE3::prepare doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php) as a guide.

Regarding the problem at hand: From the [PHP: Strings doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

Since the SQL query is enclosed in single-quotes (`'`), the `$record` variable is not parsed. In other words, what you see is what is being sent to the database, thus no rows are returned.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Thanks so much! I had the following: ```$results = $db->query('SELECT id,last_name,first_name,middle_initial,section,lot,plot,burial_date,veteran FROM burials WHERE id = $record');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray())``` and changed it to ```$results = $db->query("SELECT id,last_name,first_name,middle_initial,section,lot,plot,burial_date,veteran FROM burials WHERE id = $record");
while ($row = $results->fetchArray())```

Comment: @BashGuy Mark it as answer then .